# how can i make a JSP tag attribute's value dynamic

Tags: jsp, tags, taglib

Please suggest,how can I make "catalog.xml" dynamic

```
 <XML:parsexml  resource = "catalog.xml" toXMLObjName = "XMLDocument" >  </XML:parsexml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `resource`  attribute  in `parsexml` tag supports `Runtime` and `EL expressions`. If it supports you can pass runtime values like this:

```
<XML:parsexml resource="${param.contextFileName}" toXMLObjName = "XMLDocument" >  
</XML:parsexml>
```

Where, `${param.contextFileName}` is EL expression which resolved to the `contextFileName`  request parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit research and did the following which solved the problem---

```
"${sessionScope.fileName}"
```

instaed of

```
"catalog.xml"
```